# Get the list of invoking method name's from Hashmap put()

Tags: java, reflection, aop, aspect

Can you help me to get the list  method name's  from the HashMap put method.

```
 Book book= new Book();
        book.setTitle("The Little Prince");
        book.setAuthor("Antoine de Saint-Exupery");
        book.setPrize(9.99);
        book.setPublisher("Delux Pop-up book");
        
        
        HashMap<String,String> map= new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("title",book.getTitle());
        map.put("author",book.getAuthor());
        map.put("prize",String.valueOf(book.getPrize()));
        map.put("publisher",validatePuplisher(book.getPublisher()));
```

Excepted result is :  `book.getTitle(),book.getAuthor(),String.valueOf(book.getPrize()),validatePuplisher(book.getPublisher())`
ie just method name's not value from the method.

Comment: SO works like this: You show what you have tried and explain what does not work. It is not like, "I have a problem, please solve it for me for free". Please also explain why you would even want that information in exactly that way? I would understand if you were interested in the values to be put in the map, but why is the source code that created them relevant? During runtime you do not have the source code, you have byte code and the latter looks quite different from the former.

Comment: Maybe you have just started programming, so don't worry, we are here to help you. Maybe you want to check what byte code looks like by inspecting your target class file with `javap -c -p MyClass.class`. Then you will see that the order in which calls are created is (schematically) `Book.getPublisher()` → `MyClass.validatePublisher(String)` → `Map.put(String, String)`, i.e. when `put(..)` is called, what is inside the parentheses in the source code has already been evaluated, because this is how the JVM or computing in general works internally.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the method names used , then enclose them in double quotes to be treated as actual string .

```java
 HashMap<String,String> map= new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("title","book.getTitle()");
        map.put("author","book.getAuthor()");
        map.put("prize","book.getPrize()");
        map.put("publisher","book.getPublisher()");
```

Comment: Based on fact that in example`map.put("title",book.getTitle());` we see `"title"` we can safely assume that OP is aware of how to create Strings manually. Question is probably more about *how to convert `map.put("title",book.getTitle());` into equivalent of `map.put("title","book.getTitle()");` programmingly*.

Comment: Now that you mention it, that's probably the case. Unfortunately that's probably doomed to be an exercise in frustration, unless you start traversing the java source files themselves...